# Update DIV with JSON data and Show/Hide DIVs

Tags: jquery, json, show-hide

I have a json array like this:

```
var headerStrings = [
        "Apple",
        "Banana",
        "Pineapple",
    ];
```

This is my HTML:

```
<div id="links">
    <ul>
        <li><a>One</a></li>
        <li><a>Two</a></li>
        <li><a>Three</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="fruit">Mango</div>
<div>
    <div>Some content one</div>
    <div>Some content two</div>
    <div>Some content three</div>
</div>
```

When I click on the link 'One' I want to do two things:

1. Replace the content of the DIV #fruit to the first item in the array - Apple.
2. Show the first DIV(Some content one) and hide the other two divs

I want to do this for the other two links as well - when I click the link 'two', I want to show the DIV(Some content two) and replace the DIV #fruit to the second item in the array - Banana.

Here's what I tried:

```
var items = $('#links ul li');
items.click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var which = $(this).index();
    $('div').find('div').hide().eq(which).show();
    $('#fruit').innerHTML = data.headerStrings[which];
});
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Hi Andrew, I updated the question with what I tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pintu31/q3YJ3/)**

```
var headerStrings = [
    "Apple",
    "Banana",
    "Pineapple",
];

$('ul li a').each(function(i){
 $(this).click(function(){
     $('#fruit').html(headerStrings[i]);
     $('#content').children().hide().eq(i).show();
 });
});


<div>
<ul>
    <li><a>One</a></li>
    <li><a>Two</a></li>
    <li><a>Three</a></li>
</ul>
```

```
<div id="fruit">Mango</div>
 <div id='content'>
 <div>Some content one</div>
 <div>Some content two</div>
 <div>Some content three</div>
</div>​​​
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery templates to solve this.

[Introduction to jquery templates](http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2010/11/30/an-introduction-to-jquery-templates.aspx) will get you started.In summary , you will load all the div's and hide it, then show/hide the div according to the click. There is a [jquery toggle div method for this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/752847/switch-toggle-div-jquery)