# Toggle div visibility using onclick

Tags: jquery

I have a navigation bar and I want to show or hide menu options when you click on the headings.

Semi-code below, but what do I enter into the `onclick` to hide/show the div?

```
<a href=link onclick=?>MENU 1</a>
  <div id='menu1'>
    Option 1
    Option 2
    Option 3
    </div>
```

Comment: [so] is not a **replacement** for Google. Where exactly are you having problems with this?

Comment: Same reply could be posted on any question on this site. Google directed me here. It is a question based coding site is it not?

Comment: Google did **not** direct you to ask a new question - this is something that you decided to do. You have not addressed my question though.. Where exactly are you having problems with this?

Comment: @JamalLanten yes, but Lix's point is that you could have found this answer by looking around at existing content instead of asking a new beginner-level question

Comment: possible duplicate of [Switch/toggle div (jquery)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/752847/switch-toggle-div-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
$('a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#menu1').toggle();
})
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GQ2UD/)**

Comment: This is the reason there are so many zero effort question on [so]. I realize that you're just trying to help. But don't you want the OP to at least *try* to help themselves first before posting here? I'm hinting towards the whole "teach a man to fish" story...

Comment: Be aware that `toggle` has been deprecated since JQuery 1.8, and was removed in 1.9.

Comment: @ElGavilan toggle(function...function... is removed but not the function toggle itself http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: I have about 5 headings with sub menus to open, would this work?

Comment: @JamalLanten No, it's not. You need to provide all relevant HTML markup since current markup is not enough detail